# How to set into query string the Replace Statement in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, str-replace

This is my problem.. but i will show example to make it simpler

I have a stored proc named usp_Replace. This sp will replace quotation marks with whitespace. 
This is the original query without setting it into query string..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Replace 
@desc varchar(50)

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;



SELECT '' + Replace(REPLACE(REPLACE(@desc, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ''),'"','') + ''

END
```

but..
I want to set the select statement into query string because for some reason I will have to use condition statement but will not show it as it is not part of the problem.

Here..

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_Replace
@desc varchar(50)

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @condition nvarchar(max)

SET @condition = null
SET @query = ' SELECT '' + Replace(REPLACE(REPLACE('''+@desc+''', CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ''),''"'','') + '' '

    SET @query = @query + ISNULL(@condition,'') 
    EXEC sp_executesql @query 

END
```

I'm getting error on this, resulting that there is unclosed quotation marks.
I'm really having problem with how and where to put single quotation marks.

Please help, if you have encountered this problem or any links/suggestions. I will be glad to learn about it. Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a bad attempt to fix sql injection issues, when you should just be using parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote all the single in the string, including the empty string.  So, `''` becomes `''''`:

```
SET @query = 'SELECT Replace(REPLACE(REPLACE(@desc, CHAR(13), ''''), CHAR(10), ''''),'' " '', '''')  '
```

I'm not sure what the empty strings were doing at the beginning and end, so I just removed them.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help. I tried your code and no error was encountered but the code doesn't replace the quotation mark/s with empty string.

Comment: @user3818587 . . . You have spaces around the double quotes in both your queries.

Comment: Thank you so much, I removed the spaces and it worked. :) Thanks a lot.